# jq crashing under Windows 10 using any command

Tags: windows, jq

I've used jq on Mac/Unix successfully for several years and have now been asked to port a project from Mac to Windows.

My problem is that I am unable to run any command in jq under Windows with the .json files that work perfectly on the Mac.

This includes the simplest command:

jq -r . /path/to/json.json

All commands cause a crash of jq. I'm running Windows 10 Pro.

What I've tried:

-Installing jq using chocolatey as well as downloading the precompiled 32-bit and 64-bit binaries directly.

-Using a standard command prompt, an elevated command prompt and PowerShell.

The .json files all have UTF-8 encoding without BOM and I've tried them with both Windows and Unix line endings. jq crashes regardless.

Can anyone please provide any guidance as to why a simple port to Windows would be so problematic, or maybe some simple issue I am overlooking?

Thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on "unable to run" and "crash". Mention what _exactly_ happens.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The jq executable was failing each time *any* command was executed. This is what's in the Event Viewer for each crash: 

Fault bucket 120306977701, type 4
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: jq.exe
P2: 0.0.0.0
P3: 55d01b38
P4: jq.exe
P5: 0.0.0.0
P6: 55d01b38
P7: c0000005
P8: 000000000000bb5f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This includes the simplest command:
>
> jq -r . /path/to/json.json

To ascertain the nature of the problem, it would probably be better to start with an even simpler command, such as:

```
jq -n .
```

If that fails, maybe there is a 32-bit/64-bit mismatch.

Also, when specifying pathnames, you will have to use Windows conventions.

Please note that jq 1.5 cannot handle long Windows pathnames.  You can obtain a more recent version of jq pre-compiled for Windows from Appveyor, as explained at
https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Installation#windows-using-appveyor

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Here's an example command that crashes jq:

jq  -r . "C:\Users\William Buckingham\Desktop\Hudson Printing JSON2CSV-XML\JSON_Examples\psc_0001c0d17516a47f.json"

Comment: I really *appreciate* the Appveyor advice. I was able to download a recent build that handles the file path issue. I now have a working installation! Thanks again.